# Hibernate works in console, not in power menu

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, power-management, hibernate

Running `sudo hibernate` in console works just fine, and allows me to restore it, but using the hibernate option on the power menu just shuts down the computer, losing my session. I enabled it in the correct file, and installed the `hibernate` package. I've read somewhere about using `pm-hibernate` but I don't have `pm-utils` installed. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just fixed it. The reason for this behavior in my case was that `/usr/sbin/hibernate` script always requires to be run as `root` and because of this you must type `sudo hibernate` to run it. When you are pressing a button in the power menu, you are doing it without root privileges. To fix this I did the following:

1. I added `alias hibernate='sudo hibernate'` to my `.bash_aliases` file.
2. Then I added `bobeff ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/hibernate` to my `/etc/sudoers` file.

The change in `/etc/sudoers` is needed to disable requirement to enter password for sudo command when executing `/usr/sbin/hybernate` script. Of course, you have to put your username instead `bobeff`. Also you have to make sure that your `.bash_aliases` file is included in your `.bashrc` file. Put the following lines in it in the case they are missing.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

This seems to work for me.